# Why replace an existing keyword in C/C++ with a macro?

Tags: c++, c, macros

I often come across keywords or one-word identifiers defined with another name. For example, `boost` defines `noexcept` as `BOOST_NOEXCEPT`, some C++ standard libraries replace `[[nodiscard]]` with `_NODISCARD`, Windows API is prone to introduce their own macros as well, and so forth. I didn't really manage to find anything which would explain this.

This makes an unfamiliar person search for what such macros mean which therefore makes the code a bit harder to understand (at least this is how I see it). Why is such tendency so widespread? What is the purpose of replacing existing one-word constructs with macros?

Comment: I guess it's for flexibility in a codebase which has to run on a variety of different compilers (there's often a `config.h` file to define all these macros for any particular compiler).  An IDE with a 'Jump to Definition' feature is a big help in cases like this.

Comment: Some code has to work across many different standards and many different compilers that don't agree on how to do particular things. Using macros that can be defined or not is a way to manage that.

Comment: *"This makes an unfamiliar person search for what such macros mean"*. It shouldn't, these macros are for internal use by the library. You shouldn't use them and it shouldn't matter what these macros expand to.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux In the case of the WIN32 API, you do have to get to grips with (some of) them, unfortunately.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most useful case of these is when you target both compilers that support a new feature and ones that do not.
For instance:

```
#if CompilerSupportsNoexcept
#define NOEXCEPT noexcept
#else
#define NOEXCEPT
#endif
```

Comment: Also worth mention that for language versions that predates ones which introduced a particular feature there is often a compiler extention which does that. Unique for each compiler.

Answer (score 6):

This may be used in different scenarios for flexibility and code clarity.
Following cases come in mind:

- support for different compilers, which implements the same feature in a different way or do not support at all
- support for different build options, i.e. building static vs dynamic library
- support for different OSes (functions, exported by dynamic libraries, in Windows and Linux would have different signatures)
- Debug vs Release builds